# Удаление записи из foreach в частичном представлении ASP.NET CORE через AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

Есть частичное представление

```
<div class="result2">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ThermLossesDataInput.LyingTypeOne)</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (ThermLossesDataInput item in Model.ListThermLossesDataInputs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.LyingTypeOne</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post">
                       //один из способов (пробовал через ViewBag)
                        @{ ViewBag.ThermLossesDataInputId = item.ThermLossesDataInputId; }
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.ThermLossesDataInputId" />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="delete" value="del" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Я пытался через AJAX передать значения для удаления строки:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#delete').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                // вариант с неправильными данными??? какой должен быть URL.Action?
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteDataInputWaterPipelines", "ThermLosses", new { ViewBag.ThermLossesDataInputId })', 

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
            });
         });
```

И контроллер:

```
  [HttpPost]                                              // 0!!
    public IActionResult DeleteDataInputWaterPipelines(int ThermLossesDataInputId)
    {

        WaterPipelineViewModel model = new WaterPipelineViewModel();
        ThermLossesDataInput thermLossesDataInput = _context.ThermLossesDataInputs.SingleOrDefault(m=>m.ThermLossesDataInputId == ThermLossesDataInputId);
        int thermLossesMainId = thermLossesDataInput.ThermLossesMainId;

        _context.ThermLossesDataInputs.Remove(thermLossesDataInput);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        model.ListThermLossesDataInputs = _context.ThermLossesDataInputs.Where(m => m.ThermLossesMainId == thermLossesMainId).ToList();
        return PartialView("_DataTable", model);
    }
```

Я перепробовал различные способы, в контроллер постоянно приходит 0 (пустое значение).

Comment: Думаю... вам будет проще коллекцию поправить. Создайте обвёртку для ListThermLossesDataInputs - тут два способа - простой - создать List и заполнить как надо, и посложнее - создать IEnumerate или что-то подобное, обвернуть им IEnumerate(ListThermLossesDataInputs), и скипать ненужные елементы. Ну и есть нудный вариант - подчищать лишне js-скриптом. Может https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700635/filter-ienumerable это поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все намного проще, нужно было не через `Razor` передавать значение, а через `value`.

Представление:

```
 <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" value="@item.ThermLossesDataInputId" id="thdi"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="delete" value="del" />
 </form>
```

Скрипт выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#delete').click(function () {
                var id = $('#thdi').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { 'id' : id },
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteDataInputWaterPipelines", "ThermLosses")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }

                });
            });
```